# I would like to know how to actually update an on object by a user who created it

Tags: python, django

I'd like to know how to update an object that was created by a User(hunter). Here is the model of the product below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    url = models.TextField()
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the create method which is made for creating an object:

```
def create(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body'] and request.POST['url'] and request.FILES['icon'] and request.FILES['image']:
      product = Product()
      product.title = request.POST['title']
      product.body = request.POST['body']
      if request.POST['url'].startswith('http://') or request.POST['url'].startswith('https://'):
        product.url = request.POST['url']
      else:
        product.url = 'http://' + request.POST['url']
      product.icon = request.FILES['icon']
      product.image = request.FILES['image']
      product.pub_date = timezone.datetime.now()
      product.hunter = request.user
      product.save()
      return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

Can you please help me create an update method so that only a user who created this product can delete it?

Comment: I don't have an answer because your question is not very specific. However, you should first look into using [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Comment: Look into using the generic views from Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: I have a create.html where the method='POST' for the form. I would need to create update.html which is similar but how to update it im not sure how

Comment: If you use a ModelForm you will not have to individually extract each attribute from request.POST. Once you have that sorted, you can then use the same form and template for an update form. Once you have the update view set up, you can have some logic that rejects or redirects the user based on `if product.user == request.user`

Comment: I am little confused. so once I created this object and Have listView and CreateView?